# CSS counter unexpected reset "when nested"

Tags: html, css

I use css counters to format some pages on a wiki (I can add CSS in the wiki page).
I use counters to number my headers.

That is a working piece of code:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    body {
    counter-reset: h1counter;
    }
    #main-content h1 {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #D1DEF1;
        counter-reset: h2counter;
        border-top: 1px dotted #000;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    }
    #main-content h1:before {
        content: counter(h1counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
        counter-increment: h1counter;
    }
    #main-content h2 {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #D1DEF1;
        counter-reset: h3counter;
        border-top: 1px dotted #000;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    }
    #main-content h2:before {
        content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
        counter-increment: h2counter;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <h1>one</h1>
        <h2>one.one</h2>
        <h2>one.two</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I use some other formatting features of my wiki (page layout), it changes the html in this way (simplified):

```
<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="hzlayout">
            <h1>one</h1>
            <h2>one.one</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="hzlayout">
            <h2>one.two</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now the numbering is broken:

[image]

I cannot figure out why h2counter is reset when going out of .hzlayout div (or when entering the second .hzlayout div)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's the way css counters work. They are based on parent containers.

Comment: Ok, thx. So no way to achieve what I want: number h1, h2, ... when they have not the same parent?

Comment: @Nico use CSS `counters()` function rather than `counter()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counters()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establish your counters at a common ancestor. Use counter-set rather that counter-reset to reinitialise your counters. So:

```css
  #main-content {
    counter-reset: h1counter h2counter h3counter;
  }
  #main-content h1 {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #D1DEF1;
      counter-set: h2counter;
      border-top: 1px dotted #000;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  }
  #main-content h1:before {
      content: counter(h1counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
      counter-increment: h1counter;
  }
  #main-content h2 {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #D1DEF1;
      counter-set: h3counter;
      border-top: 1px dotted #000;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  }
  #main-content h2:before {
      content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
      counter-increment: h2counter;
  }
  #main-content h3:before {
      content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter)  "." counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
      counter-increment: h3counter;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div class="hzlayout">
    <h1>one</h1>
    <h2>one.one</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hzlayout">
    <h2>one.two</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hzlayout">
    <h1>two</h1>
    <h2>two.one</h2>
    <h3>two.one.one</h3>
    <h3>two.one.two</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hzlayout">
    <h2>two.two</h2>
    <h2>two.three</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```